# Has anyone had issues with npx create-next-app with tailwind similar to this? "Could not download with-tailwindcss" because of a connectivity..."

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

npx create-next-app --example with-tailwindcss with-tailwindcss-app
Creating a new Next.js app in C:\Users\Dan\OneDrive\Desktop\Schematic\Test VScode\VSCode Projects\with-tailwindcss-app.

Downloading files for example with-tailwindcss. This might take a moment.

? Could not download "with-tailwindcss" because of a connectivity issue between your
machine and GitHub.
√ Could not download "with-tailwindcss" because of a connectivity issue between your
machine and GitHub.
Do you want to use the default template instead? ... no

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue,

A new version of `create-next-app` is available! 
You can update by running: `npm install --global create-next-app`

Updating it solved the issue form me.

Comment: Thank you this worked and solved it